# within a loop only one element is being appended to the div

Tags: jquery

I am new to javascript and Jquery , strugling to satisfy the screen requirements , so please excuse if the questions are dumb

Previusly i was working with static code (taht is text1 and text2 are static)

So i was apending data this way and its working fine .

```
var text1 = "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML";
var text2 = "Honey with Carmel  10 ML";


$('#topping_tsection_'+id_attr_val).append('<aside><h6 class="tdHeading">'+name+ n+'</h6> \
    <section class="secclass"> \
    <a href="#">'+text1+'</a> \
    </section>  \
    <section class="secclass"> \
    <a href="#">'+text2+'</a> \
    </section> \
    </aside>');
```

All the above is working fine

But at present i am fetching text1 and text2 dynamically this way

```
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function() {

    var str = '';
    $("#topping_tsection_" + id_attr_val + " aside:first a").each(function() {
        var category = $(this).text();
        str += '<aside><h6 class="tdHeading">' + name + n + '</h6><section class="secclass"><a href="#">' + category + '</a></section>'$('#topping_tsection_' + id_attr_val).append(str);
    });

});
```

But with this i see that only one text (Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML)is being added to the div

This is the section response

```
<section id="topping_tsection_59">
   <i id="topping-close"></i>
   <aside>
      <h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml0</h6>
      <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
      <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
      <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
   </aside>
   <aside>
      <h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml1</h6>
      <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
      <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
      <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
   </aside>
</section>
```

could anybody please let me know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Et2/25/

I wasn't sure what your actual source looks like so I had to improvise a little bit:

HTML:

```
<div id="jsfiddle"> <a href="#" class=".plus">[+]</a>

    <section id="topping_tsection_59"> <i id="topping-close"></i>

        <aside>
             <h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml0</h6>

            <!-- <img src="images/arrow-topping.png" />-->
            <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a>

            </section>
            <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a>

            </section>
        </aside>
        <aside>
             <h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml1</h6>

            <!-- <img src="images/arrow-topping.png" />-->
            <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a>

            </section>
            <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a>

            </section>
        </aside>
    </section>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('document reqady');
    $(document).on("click", "a", function () {
        // Just to make it work:
        console.log('click event');
        id_attr_val = "59";
        var n = 1;
        var str = '';
        $("#topping_tsection_" + id_attr_val + " aside:first a").each(function () {
            n++;
            console.log(this);
            var category = $(this).text();
            str += '<aside><h6 class="tdHeading">' + name + n + '</h6><section class="secclass"><a href="#">' + category + '</a></section>';
            $('#topping_tsection_' + id_attr_val).append(str);
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because selecting element using ID, and for ID it will return only one.

```
$("#topping_tsection_" + id_attr_val + " aside:first a")
```

you should select such element using class i.e. css Class name is topping section

```
$('section[id^="topping_tsection_"]').each(function() {
             var category =   $(this).find('aside:first a').text();
str += '<aside><h6 class="tdHeading">' + name + n + '</h6><section class="secclass"><a href="#">' + category + '</a></section>'$('#topping_tsection_' + id_attr_val).append(str);
            });
```

explaination:
select all section whose id starts with 'topping_tsection_', after that take its first side tag hyperlink text. and rest as it is.